# Why won't my swagger PUT or POST?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I am using Swagger 2.0 and my definition is:

```
{
  "/users/{UserId}": {
    "get": {
      "summary": "Get a specific user by id",
      "description": "",
      "parameters": [{
        "name": "UserId",
        "in": "path",
        "description": "Id of the User.",
        "required": true,
        "type": "string"
      }],
      "tags": [
        "Users"
      ],
      "responses": {
        "200": {
          "description": "An specific user",
          "schema": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/User"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "put": {
      "summary": "Update a User",
      "description": "",
      "consumes": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      "parameters": [{
        "name": "UserId",
        "in": "path",
        "description": "Id of the user.",
        "required": true,
        "type": "string"
      }, {
        "name": "name",
        "in": "formData",
        "description": "Name of the user",
        "required": false,
        "type": "string"
      }, {
        "name": "username",
        "in": "formData",
        "description": "Username of the user. Must be unique and cannot have spaces.",
        "required": false,
        "type": "string"
      }, {
        "name": "email",
        "in": "formData",
        "description": "Email of the user. Must be unique.",
        "required": false,
        "type": "string"
      }, {
        "name": "entities",
        "in": "formData",
        "description": "Entities that the user is associated with.",
        "required": false,
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
          "name": "entity_id",
          "type": "string"
        }
      }],
      "tags": [
        "Users"
      ],
      "responses": {
        "200": {
          "description": "successful operation",
          "schema": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/User"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But in my swagger UI, I am trying to PUT some data, as per the UI:
[image]

But when it does the request, it does not send anything in the body. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which version of the UI do you use? Check the top of the swagger-ui.js file.

Comment: // swagger-ui.js
// version 2.1.0-alpha.7

Comment: Try updating to master. There was a bug related to form data parameters.

Comment: Can you link me to the issue on github?

Comment: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/838

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was an issue with one of the alpha releases (https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/838). The M1 releases (currently master) solve that issue.